# Rapid creation of nD array from generator yielding numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

I have a generator that yields NumPy arrays, and need a way to rapidly construct another NumPy array from the results of the generator (array of arrays) by taking a specific number of yields from the generator. Speed is the critical aspect in my problem. I've tried `np.fromiter` but it seems it doesn't support constructing from arrays:

```py
import numpy as np

def generator():
    for i in range(5):
        yield np.array([i]*10)


arr = np.fromiter(iter(generator()), dtype=np.ndarray, count=3)
```

This throws an error, as described in several other SO posts:

[Calling np.sum(np.fromiter(generator))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60149857/calling-np-sumnp-fromitergenerator)

[Numpy ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32722701/numpy-valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence)

However, I haven't found any answer that offers a rapid way to source arrays from the generator without having to do:

```py
it = iter(generator())
arr = np.array([next(it) for _ in range(3)])
```

Here it is indeed shown that `np.fromiter` is much faster: [Faster way to convert list of objects to numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30012362/faster-way-to-convert-list-of-objects-to-numpy-array)

Is it possible to rapidly source numpy arrays from the generator without having use the slow list to array conversion? I specifically want to avoid the `np.array(list(...))` construct, because I will be calling it hundreds of thousands of times, and the delay will eventually add up and make a big difference in execution time.

Comment: What's the shape of these arrays?  Always the same?  Dtype?  `dtype=np.array` is the same as `dtype=object`.  What `shape` and `dtype` do you expect.

Comment: @hpaulj Didn't know you can specify those in the `dtype` in all honesty. The expected arrays are 3D arrays (images) of type `np.float32`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today this issue has been fixed on most up-to-date NumPy versions. Therefore this now works:

```py
import numpy as np

def generator():
    for i in range(5):
        yield np.array([i]*10)

arr = np.fromiter(iter(generator()), dtype=np.ndarray, count=3)
```

However, you will get an array of array objects, not a collated matrix. In order to fix this, you can simply change the last line:

```py
arr = np.vstack(np.fromiter(iter(generator()), dtype=np.ndarray, count=3))

print(arr.shape)
# prints (3, 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)?

```
from itertools import islice
g = generator()
arr = np.array(list(islice(g, 3)))

# or in one line:
# arr = np.array(list(islice(generator(), 3
```

output:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

Comment: You use exactly what I'm trying to avoid using, as described in the post: `np.array(list(...))` but also add an additional function call

Comment: @JackAvante you should describe your exact use case. `numpy.fromiter` doesn't work on iter**ators** but on iter**ables**. I think the array constructor requires to know the size of the underlying object, which an iter**ator** cannot provide. Also, **one** function call is negligible unless you want to apply this operation many times?

Comment: Indeed, this operation will be happening many times, which I should've mentioned, that is my bad. That is why speed is the most important aspect. My generator function will provide 3-dimensional numpy arrays (images), which will be loaded very often and repetitively using that same function, so I want to completely avoid the `np.array(list(...))` construction altogether if possible, since it will add up over hundreds of thousands of iterations.

Comment: @JackAvante, did you manage to solve that? I am facing a problem quite similar to yours

Comment: @Aenaon Yes, actually. I will submit a new answer to help you out.